# Bash script print the word after the match

Tags: grep

I'm trying to check if time clock is synchronized via bash script.

So first i have executed the command `timedatectl` which outputs the following:

```
Local time: Mi 2021-03-17 12:52:53 CET
              Universal time: Mi 2021-03-17 11:52:53 UTC
                    RTC time: Mi 2021-03-17 11:52:53
                   Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CET, +0100)
   System clock synchronized: yes
   systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
             RTC in local TZ: no
```

So the goal is to get the value of `System clock synchronized` which is `yes` and assign it to a variable and print it. therefore i did the follwing:

```
1-# check if time synchronized
2-syncTime="$(timedatectl | grep 'System clock')" # returns the whole line
3-echo "$syncTime"# make sure the line is saved
4-ifTimeSynched="$( $syncTime | grep -oP 'synchronized: \K\w+')"  # this supposes to save the word 
                                                                 after synchronized:  
echo "$ifTimeSynched"
```

Line 4 should get the word next to the word `synchronized`: which is in this case the `yes`However, when i print `$ifTimeSynched` as shown above, it returns and empty line.

Any reason why it doesn't catch the word `yes`?

thank in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be easily done with using `awk`. You need to search for string `System clock synchronized` in output of your command `timedatectl`(which is passed as an input to `awk` command) and print desired column(field) which is last field in your case.

```
ifTimeSynched=$(timedatectl | awk '/System clock synchronized/{print $NF}')
echo "$ifTimeSynched"
```

Comment: HI there. Csn you please give me a hand with this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67359144/edit-a-file-based-on-users-input-using-bash-script/67359355?noredirect=1#comment119062395_67359355

Answer (score 2):

try:

`ifTimeSynched=$( echo $syncTime | grep -oP 'synchronized: \K\w+')`