# Edit a file based on user's input using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, kernel

I have the following file.dev

```
        1 DEVICES {
        2            GLOBAL-CONFIG {
        3               framerate = "20000";
        4               subframes = "0";
        5               max_consec_timeouts = "10";
        6               max_total_timeouts = "1000";
        7               schedmode = "Standard";
        8               clustermode = "Standard";
        9           }
        10           IO-DEVICES {
        11            }
        12           COMPUTING-DEVICES {
        13                RT_WORKSTATION FDT-C-XM-0120 = {
        14                    hostname = "FDT-C-XM-0120";
        15                    ipaddress = "fdt-c-XM-0120.fdtel.exter";
        16                    DISPLAYS {
        17                        main = "FDT-C-XM-0120:0.0";
        18                    }
        19                    SCHEDPARAM {
        20                        active = "0";
        21                        framerate = "20000";
        22                        subframes = "0";
        23                        max_consec_timeouts = "10";
        24                        max_total_timeouts = "1000";
        25                    }
        26                }
        27              
        28              RT_HOST fdt-c-agx-0008 = { 
        29                    hostname = "fdt-c-agx-0008";
        30                    ipaddress = "fdt-c-agx-0008";
        31                    SCHEDPARAM {
        32                        active = "0";
        33                        framerate = "20000";
        34                        subframes = "0";
        35                        max_consec_timeouts = "10";
        36                        max_total_timeouts = "1000";
        37                    }
        38                }
        39              
        40    #             RT_HOST fdt-c-agx-0003 = { 
        41    #                    hostname = "fdt-c-agx-0003";
        42    #                   ipaddress = "fdt-c-agx-0003.fdtel.exter";
        43    #                    SCHEDPARAM {
        44    #                        active = "0";
        45    #                        framerate = "20000";
        46    #                        subframes = "0";
        47    #                        max_consec_timeouts = "10";
        48    #                        max_total_timeouts = "1000";
        49    #                    }
        50    #                }
        51            }
        52        }
```

In this file the text parts  **part 1** `(from line 28 till 38)` and  **part 2** `(from line 40 till 50)` are parts which the user switch between. As we can see part 2 is commented out and part one is active.

So i'm trying to automate that using bash script in such a way that the user only enters the part number he wants and the other is commented out. This way the use must not comment out each line.

```
# example
if [ "$userEntry" = "part2"]
then
deactivate part one by typing adding from line 28 till 38 and activate part 2 by removing the #
```

and the output would look like

```
        1 DEVICES {
        2            GLOBAL-CONFIG {
        3               framerate = "20000";
        4               subframes = "0";
        5               max_consec_timeouts = "10";
        6               max_total_timeouts = "1000";
        7               schedmode = "Standard";
        8               clustermode = "Standard";
        9           }
        10           IO-DEVICES {
        11            }
        12           COMPUTING-DEVICES {
        13                RT_WORKSTATION FDT-C-XM-0120 = {
        14                    hostname = "FDT-C-XM-0120";
        15                    ipaddress = "fdt-c-XM-0120.fdtel.exter";
        16                    DISPLAYS {
        17                        main = "FDT-C-XM-0120:0.0";
        18                    }
        19                    SCHEDPARAM {
        20                        active = "0";
        21                        framerate = "20000";
        22                        subframes = "0";
        23                        max_consec_timeouts = "10";
        24                        max_total_timeouts = "1000";
        25                    }
        26                }
        27              
        28  #           RT_HOST fdt-c-agx-0008 = { 
        29  #                  hostname = "fdt-c-agx-0008";
        30  #                  ipaddress = "fdt-c-agx-0008";
        31  #                  SCHEDPARAM {
        32  #                      active = "0";
        33  #                      framerate = "20000";
        34  #                      subframes = "0";
        35  #                      max_consec_timeouts = "10";
        36  #                      max_total_timeouts = "1000";
        37  #                  }
        38  #              }
        39              
        40                  RT_HOST fdt-c-agx-0003 = { 
        41                        hostname = "fdt-c-agx-0003";
        42                       ipaddress = "fdt-c-agx-0003.fdtel.exter";
        43                        SCHEDPARAM {
        44                            active = "0";
        45                            framerate = "20000";
        46                            subframes = "0";
        47                            max_consec_timeouts = "10";
        48                            max_total_timeouts = "1000";
        49                        }
        50                    }
        51            }
        52        }
```

Note that the lines order in the file.dev do not change.

I hope i could make my question clear and thanks in advance

Comment: There is just one thing, how do the user know if either _part1_ or _part2_ is enabled?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128593/simplest-way-to-comment-uncomment-certain-lines-using-command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ed` if it is available/acceptable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ "$userEntry" == "part2" ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' '40,50s/^[[:blank:]]*#//' '28,38s/^/#/' ,p Q |
  ed -s file.txt
fi
```

Will just print the new output to `stdout` but the file will not be change/edited. Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is needed. Remove the `,p` to silence the output.

---

With `sed`

```
sed '40,50s/^[[:blank:]]*#//;28,38s/^/#/' file.txt
```

Note that different `sed` version has different syntax when using the `-i` flag if *in-place* editing is needed.

---

As per the OP's explanation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

part1=28
part2=40

if [[ "$userEntry" == "part2" ]]; then
  if [[ $(grep -nm1 \# file.txt | cut -d':' -f1) == "$part2" ]]; then
     sed '40,50s/^[[:blank:]]*#*//;28,38s/^/#/' file.txt
  else
     sed '28,38s/^/#/' file.txt
  fi
elif [[ "$userEntry" == "part1" ]]; then
  if [[ $(grep -nm1 \# file.txt | cut -d':' -f1) == "$part1" ]]; then
     sed '28,38s/^[[:blank:]]*#*//;40,50s/^/#/' file.txt
  else
     sed '40,50s/^/#/' file.txt
  fi
fi
```

Requites GNU `grep(1)`

Comment: thanks alot. I tried your code. it returns the following error test.sh: `line 9: ed: command not found`. Yes the change must be saved in the file

Comment: Well, `ed` is not installed so use `sed` with the `-i` flag/option to edit the file.

Comment: when applying sed with flag -i, it write #  correctly however, in the question it is meant that if user enters part1, then the # must be removed in part one (in case its outcommented) and thus becomes active code and part2 should be commented with # and thus becomes inactive and vice versa

Comment: i mean either part 1 or part 2 is commented out and the user's entry tells which part to activate which means to delete the # if already exists in the part to be activated and add the # to the other part. I hope i've made my self clear :)

Comment: I could extract a solution from your answer however like `#if part1 is to activate
sed -i '28,38s/^[[:blank:]]*#//;28,38s/^/ /' devices.dev
sed -i '28,38s/^[[:blank:]]*#//;40,50s/^/#/' devices.dev`

`#if part2 to activate
sed -i '40,50s/^[[:blank:]]*#//;28,38s/^/ /' devices.dev
sed -i '40,50s/^[[:blank:]]*#//;28,38s/^/#/' devices.dev`. However, by multiple executions it double writes the # and thus both parts are still commented out

Comment: I have posted a new solution, try it out, I did no add the `-i` flag though.

Comment: Exactly this works perfectly. When for example the user enters for the first time part2 it works. By second execution if the user enters also part2 it double writes the # on the part1 and so on which not a problem. However, by fourth execution, the user enters part1, it deletes only one coloum of the # by part1 however still two columns of # remaining, while it must delete all # for the selected part which in this case part 1

Comment: perfect. you're really a gold mine. Thanks alot